# Proving entireness of a piecewise function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

[image]

I have tried solving this problem with this strategy.  We know that if a function has a power series representation with radius of convergence R, it is analytic on that radius.  I can clearly get infinite radius of convergence for the upper part of the piecewise function, implying that g is analytic everywhere except maybe 0.  I need to check that g(z) is differentiable at 0, but unfortunately, we are not allowed to use L'Hoptial's rule.  I know the limit of the upper half as g approaches 0 is 1/2, by looking at the series expansion.  Any ides on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, the only possible issue is at $0$. The upper piece has a singularity at $0$; try determining what kind of singularity it is.

Since the power series converges at 0 to g(0), we know more than that g is continuous at 0 -- we know g is analytic at 0.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But I can only tell that the upper part has a point singularity at 0 that goes to infinity.  I am still stuck.

Comment: @MathGuyForLife Hmm. I don't think you're right about that. Try expanding $\cos z$

Comment: So the upper part's limit goes to 1/2.  Not sure what to do from there.

Comment: @MathGuyForLife That makes it a removable singularity. If you're not familiar with the properties of removable singularities, try writing out the power series representation you referenced in your question; does it converge at $0$?

Comment: Yes, the power series converges to 1/2  as I said above, which means g is continuous at 0, but why does that mean that g is differrentiable there?  I set up the limit definition of derivatives, and I get to a situation where I need L'hopital's rule to solve, which we cannot use.

Comment: @MathGuyForLife Since the power series converges at $0$ to $g(0)$, we know more than that $g$ is continuous at $0$ -- we know $g$ is analytic at $0$. As you said in your question, "We know that if a function has a power series representation with radius of convergence R, it is analytic on that radius."